# How to find strong in previous div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML with id automatically generated (I don't know elements id)

HTML is like :

```
<div id='maindiv">
    <div class="clearfix time">
        <h6><strong>5 septembre 2014</strong> 15:18</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m1" class="clearfix received">
        <p>Message ouvert 1</p>
        <span id="o1"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="m2" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>Message ouvert 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time" style="text-align: center;">
        <h6><strong>18 septembre 2014</strong> 13:51</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m3" class="clearfix received">
        <p>Message ouvert et supprimer pour Xavier - 1</p>
        <span id="o3"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time" style="text-align: center;">
        <h6>16:14</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m5" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o5" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>Message ouvert et supprimer pour Xavier - 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time" style="text-align: center;">
        <h6><strong>23 septembre 2014</strong> 20:01</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m7" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o7" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>Message non lu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="m9" class="clearfix received">
        <p>Message non lu par X4V1 mais supprimé par Xavier</p>
        <span id="o9"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="m10" class="clearfix received">
        <p>Message non lu</p>
        <span id="o10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time">
        <h6><strong>25 septembre 2014</strong> 17:54</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m13" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o13" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time">
        <h6><strong>26 septembre 2014</strong> 14:18</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m14" class="clearfix received">
        <p><img src="http://localhost/PrivateChat/public/smilies/Smile.png"></p>
        <span id="o14"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix time">
        <h6><strong>28 septembre 2014</strong> 00:57</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="m24" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o24" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>salut</p>
    </div><div id="m25" class="clearfix sent">
        <span id="o25" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        <p>salut2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I select a specific message like m14 (id is given by server) I have to find the previous div which contain strong tag inside h6 tag (first on top of my m14 div) I can find the previous div with time like

```
$('#m'+id).prev('.time')
```

but It doesn't check if there is a strong tag inside. I can do the work with this but I have to use a "for" and it's slower than using the right command in jquery.

What I'm looking for is to get html code inside strong tag inside h6 inside div.time for all

Do you know how I can find that?

Comment: You mean you are looking for `.find()`?

Comment: Since you already have the prev worked out, just check for `h6 strong`'s length

Comment: I think it is possible with find but I can't find the first div on top of my element with .time > h6 > strong. Maybe someone can explain me how it work to find the first on top (at the same level)

Comment: @X4V1 what he meant was use `find()` after you got the prev `.time` like this `$('#m'+id).prev('.time').find('h6 strong')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you want is to get *all* the preceding siblings with the `time` class, then filter them to just the ones with a `strong` descendant, then pick the closest one to your original element.

```
$('#m'+id).prevAll('.time').has('strong').eq(0)
```

Comment: just wow ! beautifull :)
For the content of the strong I use : $('#m'+id).prevAll('.time').has('strong').eq(0).find('strong').html(); thank you very much